# Why isn't Django Rest Framework Token Authentication working?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am currently using Django rest framework and trying to implement a Token Authentication system. Currently, my settings.py looks like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ]
}
```

and rest_framework.authtoken is in installed_apps.

My urls.py looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url('^v1/users/$', views.users_view),
    ...
]
```

My views.py looks like this:

```
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))
@api_view(['PUT', 'POST'])
def users_view(request):
...
```

I'm working in postman to test the API and regardless of whether I put the token in the authorization field, the API works as intended. What do I need to change for the token authentication to work as intended?

Update:
Reqbin is also giving me the same functionality so I don't think it's a problem with postman.

Comment: I was able to work around this by using class based views but the initial problem hasn't been addressed.

Comment: It appears I'm not alone in this issue. After much googling and research, I believe this is a bug in Django where some authenticators don't work properly with function based views. Can anyone confirm this? If so, I'll write an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is a bug in Django that won't allow some authentications to work with function based views. I can confirm it doesn't work for TokenAuthentication and needed to use class based views.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add permission class as well.

```
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
@api_view(['PUT', 'POST'])
def users_view(request):
...
```

Comment: It still works with or without the token.

Comment: How are you testing this ? Using postman ?

Comment: I'm running both a put and post method by calling the endpoint. I'm putting the post data inside the form fields of the body request and testing the token using the bearer token authorization field.